# caesar cipher does not work, can't figure why

Tags: c, cs50, caesar-cipher

I wrote my code and it seems fine, but there is something about it that just doesn't work and I can't figure out why. It is one caesar cipher but it just doesn't give me the expected output

```
int main(int key, char* argv[])
{

key = atoi(argv[1]);
string ptext = get_string("plaintext: ");
int len = strlen(ptext);
printf("%s %i\n", ptext, key);`


    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(ptext[i])){
            if (ptext[i] >= 'a' && ptext[i] <= 'z')
            {
                if (ptext[i] + key > 'z')
                {
                    printf("%c", 'a' + (key % 26)); //'a' is used to reset the ascii table so it use letters only
                }
                else{
                    printf("%c", ptext[i] + key);
                }
            if (ptext[i] >= 'A' && ptext[i] <= 'Z')
            {
                if (ptext[i] + key >= 'Z'){
                    printf("%c", (ptext[i] + (key % 26)) - 'z'); //'A' is used to reset the ascii table so it use letters only

                }
                else{
                    printf("%c", ptext[i] + key);
                }
                    }
            }
        else{
            printf("%c", ptext[i]);
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "doesn't work", "doesn't give expected output" -- Doesn't work *how*? What output do you get for what input?

Comment: if I set a key of 5 and submit "hello, hi", the output will be "mjqqtmn", when it should be "mjtt, mn". Also, when I set a key of 1 and use "zzz" it returns "bbb" instead of "aaa"

Comment: what did you see when you stepped through with your debugger

Comment: You are defining the first argument to main as `key` and then setting it to `argv[1]`. The first argument to main should be `argc` and `key` should be defined as a separate variable in main.

Comment: oh thx, that helped. Can you explain me tho? It worked but idk why it did

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect handling when `ptext[i] + key > 'z'`.

`'a' + (key % 26)` does not depend on `ptext[i]`

```
if (ptext[i] + key > 'z') {
  printf("%c", 'a' + (key % 26)); // Incorrect. 
} else {
  ....
}
```

Instead

```
int sum = (ptext[i] - 'a' + key)%26 + 'a';
printf("%c", sum);
```

Likewise for `if (ptext[i] + key >= 'Z'){`.

Comment: wait, so instead of all the if-else loops I just need to use this?

Comment: Oh, I see, I just have to use it inside the conditions, Do I use it for every single one?